# How do I fix "no symbol version for module_layout"?

Tags: linux, version, opensuse

I'm trying to compile the nvidia driver and the VirtualBox drives on openSUSE 11.2. Both compile fine (after the usual `make oldconfig` plus a partial build of the kernel) but when I try to load the modules, I get this error:

```
vboxdrv: no symbol version for module_layout
```

What's wrong? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. The package `kernel-default-devel` was missing. To install it, run this command as root:

```
zypper in kernel-default-devel
```

Comment: Verify the version of `kernel-default-devel` matches the version in the `uname -a`.

Answer (score 2):

Not cogent to openSUSE, but under Ubuntu 10, I found that the solution was:

```
apt-get install dkms
apt-get install linux-headers-2.6.32-24-generic
unset KERN_DIR
/etc/init.d/vboxadd setup 
# Although presumably if the apt-gets had been done first,
# the last two lines would be superfluous.
```

Hope this is useful to someone else down the way.